# Как проверить поле логина при регистрации?

Tags: php, регистрация

Здравствуйте.
у меня на сайте есть регистрация и одно из полей это логин пользователя.
сейчас реализована проверка на пустоту, на максимальную и минимальную длину.

Как теперь правильно проверить на корректность по строгим параметрам, а именно:

1. допускаются исключительно только буквы латинского алфавита, цифры, символ нижнего подчеркивания и тире.
2. логин должен начинаться только с буквы или цифры и заканчиваться буквой или цифрой.

может у кого то есть готовое решение? или помогите написать регулярное выражение или другим способом.

Прошу помощи в реализации.

Comment: [логин регулярные-выражения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD+%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D)

Answer (score 0):

На стороне клиента сразу проверить можно, используя javascrip валидатор. Вот регэксп для проверки `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}[a-zA-Z]$` Этот вариант рассчитан на слово 2-22 символа, границы в фигурных скобках меняются